# Creating an arraylist in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an ArrayList in java and in some code i found this line `Node head=(Node)array[b]`. In that code this line was executed for creating an ArrayList.

What is the difference between `Node head=(Node)array[index]` and `Node head=(array[index],null)`.

How does `Node head=(Node)array[b]` work??

Comment: the difference is that the second one wont compile, and it does work by casting the object in the array `array` at the index `b` to a `Node`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create an ArrayList in JAVA:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Above exaple will create an ArrayList of `String`.

> I found this line `Node head=(Node)array[b];`

This is just initializing the object of `Node` class with the value of an array named `array` of type `Node` at index `b`.

> What is the difference between `Node head=(Node)array[index]` and
>   `Node head=(array[index],null)`

`Node head=(array[index],null)` this does not make any sense to me unless you are doing something like `Node head=someFunction(array[index],null)` where you are passing the value of `array` at index `b` and `null` as parameters and it is returning you an object of type `Node`.

Comment: that was my mistake.i was trying to say that "Node head=new Node (array[index],null)".

Answer (score 1):

the way to create Array list in java is
ArrayList name of list = ArrayList<>();

in the above example your going to create the Array list type NODe class